Magento 2 : Attribute is_approved does not Contain Option With Id New
We updated to 2.4.6-P5 and get this error when a customer fills in a registration form. The same error appears when I try to create a customer account.
We work with a multistore and customers need to be approved before they see prices.
Disabling the customer approval extension did not make any difference.
Please any suggestions?

Mageplaza is sending this bug.
There is an error in the sql update of the module. https://www.mageplaza.com/releases/customer-approval/

For anyone else who wants an actual solution. Open up your database and run the following command to update the is_approved attribute set by the MagePlaza Customer Approval extension and Magento 2.4.6+. No need to update the extension version.
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `default_value` = 'pending' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`code` =  'is_approved';

The default value was set to New. This isn't an option, so setting it to pending, which is the first option on the list will fix this.
